# ternary construction not equivalent with if then else

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement

The following if/then test  (in bash):

```
if [ 1 ]; then ls /undef_dummy > /dev/null 2>&1; else echo "else stmt"; fi
```

seems not equivalent to its ternary version:

```
(test 1) && ls /undef_dummy > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo "else stmt"
```

The first one will print nothing but the second one will print "else stmt".

This is because the || operator in the ternary version relates to the return status of either the test **or** the command executed if the test passes. But usually, we want the
else statement to only relate to the test, so it's not safe to use the ternary version here.

Am I right?

Comment: why do you call the second option "ternary"? I don't think `x && y || z` is ternary in the sense of the C `x ? y : z` ternary operator. It's just the composition of two binary operators. And then, precedence decides on the outcome.

Comment: you can always do `(test 1) && (ls ... || true) || echo "else stmt"`

Comment: I should probably have said "order of evaluation" instead of "precedence".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command:

```
(test 1) && ls /undef_dummy > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo "else stmt"
```

`||` is being evaluated because `ls` is returning non-zero return code to shell

If you use this command:

```
test 1 && date || echo "else stmt"
```

Then it will print date value instead of `else stmt`

With proper grouping your command:

```
test 1 && { ls /undef_dummy > /dev/null 2>&1 || true; } || echo "else stmt"
```

**will not print anything**

Answer (score 1):

What you refer to as the *ternary version* is actually equivalent to:

```
if (test 1); then
  if ! ls /undef_dummy > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "else stmt"
  fi
fi
```

and is pretty different from saying:

```
if [ 1 ]; then ls /undef_dummy > /dev/null 2>&1; else echo "else stmt"; fi
```